# sync models without id [laravel]

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have model timesheetweek which *hasMany* (7) timesheetdays. On a view I can dynamicly add several weeks which each contain 7 inputs (1/day). fyi: each input has a date data-attribute. So each **timesheetday date field** should be *compared* to the **data-attribute** of the input.

Is there an easy way to **sync** the inputs with the models?

So let's say the input would contain the amount of hours:

- if hours == 0 : destroy the timesheetday
- if hours are the same : don't update
- if hours is different : update.

thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Laravel models exist on the server, but you're talking about attributes on the HTML elements on the client. Are you asking how to handle the data after making a `POST` request to the server with the data from your form? Or are you asking about how to make that request?

Comment: @Kryten: Sorry I've never been good at explaining something. I would like to know the easiest way to actually "c(r)ud" the timesheetdays. I could eventually use a nested foreach loop and use several if statements to compare the database model and the inputs. So this is why I actually ask this question if there is some easier way to update/create/delete my model. Like some sort of syncing method.